Tooltip of a GraphicValidationDecoration is completely hidden behind tooltip of a control
I'm trying to use http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#decorationvalidation in my project, but probably miss something very obvious, thus the question.
If my control has a tooltip, the tooltip of a validation decoration is completely obscured by the tooltip of the control. How do I give the tooltip of the validation decoration some more priority?
package de.oowv.application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.validation.ValidationResult;
import org.controlsfx.validation.ValidationSupport;
import org.controlsfx.validation.decoration.GraphicValidationDecoration;

public class Tmp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField text = new TextField();
        text.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Text tooltip"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, text);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        ValidationSupport vs = new ValidationSupport();
        vs.setValidationDecorator(new GraphicValidationDecoration());
        vs.registerValidator(text, false, (c, v) -> ValidationResult.fromError(c, "Error"));
        text.setText("MMm");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}


I do get:
tooltip of the control over validation icon
My expectation would be:
validation tooltip over validation decoration

Probably the text field tooltip is not needed at all if the validation tooltip is showing?  If so, you could monitor the validation status of the field, and set the text tooltip to a value or null depending on whether the field is valid or not.  Or, if you need both tooltips at once you might adjust the anchor location to avoid overlaps.

Or perhaps consider a different design that doesn't involve so many popups like a StyleClassValidationDecoration.  Just some thoughts, not answers.

Thank you, setting anchor does not help. GraphicDecoration#applyDecoration sets Decoration as a child of a node to decorate (Text), so tooltip area of the text node is automatically extended to cover decoration as well, whatever it is placed.

I looked into the ControlsFX validation framework to check if anything from my previous suggestions might help, (e.g only showing text field tooltip if the validation tooltip is not showing or repositioning one of the tooltips and showing both).  With the current 11.2.1 versions of ControlsFX, neither approach could be implemented easily (as noted by Slava in his comment).

I suggest you make an issue report to the ControlsFX tool team and ask them to help fix it.  There are many (currently 468) open issues with the project, so I think the likelihood of getting a quick fix unless you have the skill to create and submit a patch  yourself is probably very low.

Thank you, just created https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/1565
